# What do I do with this during SR suntour lower leg service?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, fork, suspension

I'm trying to do a lower leg service on my fork: SR Suntour Epixon  29er 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B014UQDX9Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I've removed the rebound dial expecting something to stick an allen key into as normal. Instead it is this:

[image]

What do I do with this? Do I need to pull the bit in the centre out so I can fit an allen key in? Or a socket wrench that unscrews the whole thing?

If anyone knows of a better service manual than the one provided with this fork, or service videos for this model please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[[Based on the exploded diagram](https://www.srsuntour.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Consumer/Bike/Exploded%20views/2012/Suspension%20Fork/SF12-EPICON/SF12-EPICON%20X1-DS-RL-R%20lite-15QLC-29-120-100-80-(1).PDF) it looks like each side of the fork is a little different:

[image]

Side 1 ("air side" composed of parts 5a, 5b, and 5c) looks most like your picture.
Side 2 (composed of parts 3a and 3b)looks most like what you were expecting.

[This video at 2:17](https://youtu.be/7_VeA_41WHw) shows a fork end that matches the picture in the question
[image]

You'd use a wrench on that side rather than an allen wrench.

Comment: @Swifty Thank you! - brain fart

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. The diagram is excellent, where did you find that?